# Winforms User Control MissingMethodException

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, user-controls, visual-studio-2013

So essentially, I have a custom user control called ExcelDisplay. I try to drag it over in visual studio from the toolbox into my webform in the same project and I get a missing method exception. At one time the constructor was parameterized, but I changed it after deciding it was a bad design idea.

It looks like it is saying the constructor is missing, but its obviously there.

My winform to house the control is empty with the exception of the autogenerated code visual studio puts there.

The code for my ExcelDisplay's constructor looks like this.

```
    namespace STS_Console.UserControls
    {
        public partial class ExcelDisplay : UserControl
        {

            public ExcelDisplay()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                DataDisplay.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Data";
                //debug
                string x = DataDisplay.Columns[0].GetType().ToString();
                x.ToString();
            }
```

The error message is this.
[image: error message]

So that error occurs when do I drag and drop in the designer like this
[image: Drag and drop]

Anyway so that is my problem. I am not sure what is causing it or how to fix it. I would be glad to post additional code upon request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put your user controls in a class library of their own. For the designer to work, it needs a *compiled* version of your user control. If you cannot compile your user control *before* you compile your form, you will get into all kinds of trouble.

Comment: My project is a fairly small one, taking only a few weeks. Is this necessary?

Comment: If you want to stay sane, yes. Otherwise, Visual Studio will ruin your project a few times in those weeks. It's about 5 minutes work and it will pay off big time compared to the endless frustration of not doing this. Just see this issue. How many time did you spent? It could have been 0, if you had seperated your user controls.

Answer (score 1):

Rebuild Solution fixed it for me, although if your making regular changes to your user control, you should put them into a separate project.

My particular problem, was a user control, within a user control.

Comment: The rebuild solution fixed my problem after I removed the parameterized constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe delete the .usercontrol in namespace will work

Comment: Hi, this answer seems more like a comment to me.
For answers, you typically wanna write some more, by including an explanation or why your solution works.