# Derived User Control: MissingMethodException: Constructor

Tags: c#, .net

I want to create a UserControl, derived from DataGridView:

Stripped down Example:

```
public class XXX : System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
{
    public XXX() : base()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        base.OnPaint(pe);
    }
}
```

It's in a separate DLL and I've added it successfully to the Toolbox. But when dragging it on a form, I got an Exception from Visual Studio:

```
Failed to create component 'XXX'. The error message follows:
'System.MissingMethodException: Contructor on type 'XXX' not found.
```

(Seems to be the same error as in [Winforms User Control MissingMethodException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24594348/winforms-user-control-missingmethodexception))

As seen, I have the "empty" constructor. What is wrong? Where can I search for further information?

Comment: When you add a control to the toolbox instead of letting it auto-populate from the solution content then the IDE must make a copy of the DLL.  That copy can easily become stale, no longer matching the source code.  Rebuilding the DLL, removing the control from the toolbox and adding it back is the workaround.  But having the control part of your solution is by far the best approach.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Wild Toolbox reset, restart VS and moving the source files between the projects solved the problem at last.